# How do you set the default/startup orientation for the Windows Phone 7 emulator?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, emulation

I am working on a Silverlight based Windows Phone application that only supports landscape orientation.  However, when I hit F5 to debug it, the emulator always starts in portrait mode.

Is there a way to set this to default to landscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I'm aware it is not possible, but is this a big problem? Remember you don't need to close the emulator while you stop debuging - it can stay on landscape mode and VS will connect to it.

Comment: I just noticed this behavior.  It will take a bit of time to break the habit of clicking the little 'X'.  As a benefit, leaving the emulator up is marginally faster on my machine.